# RTS synchronization disables the BOM in ILOG Jrules

Tags: business-rules, ilog, jrules

I synchronized my rule project with a rule team server in another machine. Then checked out the rule project from another machine from the RTS. I added a new member to the BOM from my second machine. Then synched it to the RTS. Now coming to my first machine , I synched the rule project. I got the updated BOM entry but alas my BOM is kind of blocked. Double clicking the member in any BOM do not allow me to edit it !! Is this a bug in Rule Studio or Am I doing the synch wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

more details please...
I far as I can remember, If you put some security on your project then only the ruleset signature will be excluded from the sync (let's call that a feature from RTS)
You said BOM...
Are you following good practices where you have a BOM project and a rule project?
It doesn't help a lot in here but this is really nice to have.

Sync is a bit tricky with JRules (Studio and RTS)
1/ you deploy from PC-a to PC-c (where RTS lies)
2/ from PC-b you import the rule project from PC-c (RTS)
3/ you add a BOM menber or whatever in your project
4/ you "publish" from PC-b to PC-c
5/ you dbl-chk that your BOM change is there in RTS 
6/ you sync PC-a with PC-c
now the problems arrive
normally you should see the changes and hence "update" (not "publish") the changes
so the files in PC-c will overwrite files in PC-a
Look at the arrows directions (in/out or RED => manual check)

 
If you have separated projects you have less thing to check and you know what to check

I agree, sync can be annoying :)

Hope it helps

Comment: after the step 6, the BOM in PC-a becomes uneditable,that is the issue I am facing. PS: I am creating the BOM from XSD.

Comment: Could you compare the BOM files in Eclipse? There an option in the Sync perspective to do so. From now, 2 options: 1/ The BOM (somehow) has been corrupted hence you may still be able to manually restore it. 2/ There is no reason and this leads to another set of 2 options: Sometimes JRules do something wrong without any reason so try to re do the process from scratch (BTW: do not forget the rule number 1 in JRules: if you are sure that it should work then restart Eclipse aand possibly RTS as well. You will keep you hairs :)

Comment: Or, if even with a simple XSD based BOM (1 complex type with 2 attribute String), the issue is still there then yes, drop an email to support. It may be a well known "feature" in this version. I hope you do not use 7.0.0 or 7.0.1 which have some strange behaviour from time to time.    XSD or JAVA, the BOM is the same business layer used to author rules at design time, containing verbalisation (languages), B2X and a business representation of your object model.

Comment: im using the latest one v7.1 , i will compare the bom & see.

Comment: can you check out this error in RTS ? I am sure its not a coding error,but some erratic thing in RTS. 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352265/jrule-is-showing-all-sorts-of-error-in-rule-team-server-but-works-good-in-rule