# JRule is showing all sorts of error in rule team server , but works good in Rule Studio

Tags: business-rules, rule-engine, ilog, jrules

I have a small rule which is running propely in Rule Studio when I tested with DVS. Now I deployed the rule to rule team server and when I opened the same rule in RTS. Its showing me all sorts of errors !. I am sure the error is not with the code,it is some issue or bug in IBM Jrules ILOG Rule Team Server. Any experts know about this bug ?  I am using a trial version of IBM JRules v7.1

Please see the below attached image which shows the error in the RTS.

[image: ILOG RTS error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the BOM is not deployed :)
If JRules is complaining about every single word in the rule then, there is something wrong with the rule project; reference to the BOM or BOM itself if contained in the same rule project.
Dbl-chk and if needed redeploy the BOM.
The only "bug" is that the deployment wizard allows you to deploy a rule project on RTS even if the referenced BOM is not deployed on RTS. This is a regression "bug".
Because I think 6.x disallowed this.

 I used 7.1.0 on my laptop for more than a year...And it worked like a charm.

Hope it helps

Comment: seems like RTS do not like any custom verbalization which I did for this particular rule , when I reverted the rule to default verbalization,the errors vanished !

Comment: custom verbalizations are usually not a problem. Did you inserted the verbalization again to see if the problem persisted?

Comment: Custom verbalization is not a problem at all. This is one of the main purpose of it. You may have trouble if you have multiple verbalization for the same object. It is possible but not recommended anyway. What do you mean by "custom verbalization"? - Just to clarify, I understood that you have a JAVA class named 'client' and you verbalized it as: 'customer'. Keep in mind that you  use the default verbalization first (by default) you deploy the BOM. If you modify the BOM in Studio and one rule as well then you need to deploy the rule and the BOM as well.

Comment: I don't know 7.1.x I only know 7.1.0 (all the version down to latest 5) but I would be surprised to face such a regression bug.

Answer (score 0):

My Asnwer sounds like a repetition of Damien, However I would mention

1) Please get the BOM Rule Project published to Rule Team Server.
2) Please deploy your other Rule Project that have a dependency on this.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to edit the project dependencies (under Manage Project), and delete the project dependencies (be sure to save after the delete) and then add them again. If that does not work, also try emptying the cache. See the suggestions in 
[Compile errors on rules in Decision Center and Rule Team Server (RTS)](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/173682/compile-errors-on-rules-in-decision-center-and-rul.html)